# Was Francisco Erwin Galicia Arrested or Detained?

Tags: arrest

Francisco Erwin Galicia was held 23 days incommunicado by CBP in Texas.  Was he arrested or detained?  What is the line of reasoning for arriving at the conclusion?

Update: [Galacia's attorney indicated](https://www.dallasnews.com/news/immigration/2019/07/29/congressman-asks-border-patrol-chief-clarify-testimony-us-citizen-held-weeks) a notice from DHS:

> The notice reads, “On or about June 27, 2019, you were found at the
>   Falfurrias, Texas, Border Patrol Checkpoint, a distance of more than
>   25 miles from the United States border with Mexico ... You did not
>   receive the permission of an immigration officer to proceed beyond
>   that 25 mile limit ... At that time, you falsely represented yourself
>   to be a citizen of the United States for the purpose of furthering
>   your entry into the United States.”

Comment: Implicit in the question is the conjecture that an arrest must be for a suspected criminal offense to count as an arrest and this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

### He was arrested and then detained

Arrest is a “point in time” event at which someone is lawfully deprived of their liberty. After that, while they are held in custody they are being detained.

Comment: In US terms, one can be detained without being arrested.  So it's probable that he was detained, then arrested, then further detained.